# Ionic app error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, api, ionic-framework

I have a mobile app developed in ionic capacitor. The backend to the app is a .net core web api deployed on amazon elastic beanstalk. I am getting CORS error** No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** when trying to access the back end using the app.

I have attempted to allow the API to be accessible by any consumer by allowing all origins. Is there need to configure anything on AWS Elastic bean?

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(builder => builder
     .AllowAnyOrigin()
     .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     );
```